# setOnMousePressed and setOnMouseDragged vs @FXML event handlers from scene builder JavaFX

Tags: javafx, event-handling, mouseevent, scenebuilder

I am trying to employ dragging my stage around via dragging a certain component on my application. 
It works perfectly like this:

```
miniTop.setOnMousePressed(e-> {
    xOffset = e.getSceneX();
    yOffset = e.getSceneY();
});
miniTop.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
    stage = (Stage) ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
    stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
});
```

But when I do this... nononon

```
@FXML
public void getOffset(MouseEvent e) {
    xOffset = e.getSceneX();
    yOffset = e.getSceneY();
}
@FXML
public void dragStage(MouseEvent e) {
    stage = (Stage) ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
    stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
}
```

where these event handlers are linked to:

[image: scene builder event handling]
I've tried encasing the `dragStage` method with a `Platform.runLater()` since it's changing the UI by moving the stage but that did not help...

What's the difference between .setOnMouse and Scene Builder event handlers?

**EDIT:** it started working after running it again after 30 mins? what? (So hard to learn when you think you've made a mistake when you haven't haha)

Comment: `Platform.runLater` is not necessary, since event handlers are run on the JavaFX application thread. There is absolutely no difference between the 2 except if you assign a different value to the `onMousePressed`/`onMouseDragged` event handlers, e.g. in the `initialize` method...

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference, the documentation available for the FXML event handlers simply links to: `javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty<javafx.event.EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>> onAction`

which is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/event/class-use/ActionEvent.html)

this would suggest they are implemented in the same way. can you check in your FXML file that the event handler was properly assigned to the element you were expecting?

Comment: How did `ActionEvent` get involved? The op is only registering to event handlers for `MouseEvent`s...